# List value changes after execution of for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list "a". after executing following for loop list values are changed

```
a=[1,2,3]
for a[0] in a:
    print(a[0])


print(a) #it prints [3, 2, 3]
```

Comment: in above shown script when i executed that for loop i got normal list values but somehow my list changed after that for loop gets executed.

Comment: Your loop variable is the first value of the list... so this will be set to 1, 2 and finally 3. And that's where it ends up.

Comment: but why original list is modified. when i changed a[0] to a[1] that print inside for loop gives 1 1 1 and then list is modified to [1,3,3]

Comment: Inside the loop you print a[0], which is not altered anymore evertime if you make a[1] the loop variable. Therefore it'll print 1 1 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
for i in [1,2,3]:
    print i
```

i = 1 and then 2 and then 3 for each iteration. So if you execute this code

```
a=[1,2,3]
for a[0] in a:
    print a[0]
    print a
```

Output:

```
1
[1, 2, 3]
2
[2, 2, 3]
3
[3, 2, 3]
```

You can clearly see that a[0] is first 1, then 2 and finally 3, so 'a' becomes [1,2,3] in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to display all the values ​​in your list.
If that's what you want to do, I advise you to use `enumerate` like this.

```
a=[1,2,4]
for index, value in enumerate(a):
        print(value)
print(a)
```

So no value in your list is changed.

Comment: Sir i know how to print all values.. But i want to know why my code is behaving unusually

Answer (score 0):

Here's what your code does split up in single commands. Maybe this way you can better understand what's going on:

```
a = [1,2,3] 
# for loop begins
a[0] = a[0]    # a is now [1,2,3]
print(a[0])    # prints 1
a[0] = a[1]    # a is now [2,2,3]
print(a[0])    # prints 2
a[0] = a[2]    # a is now [3,2,3]
print(a[0])    # prints 3
# for loop ends
print(a)       # prints [3,2,3]
```

In short: don't ever use an element of a list as a loop variable to iterate over that list with. It makes no sense, except for very special cases.

Comment: Thanks.. Got it now